# POSTGRESQL QUERY PERFORMANCE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a question regarding the query performance, My query is fetching the proper data but is pretty slow & takes around 135 seconds to execute for 1 day data. I am sure that this could be enhanced but since I lack knowledge of database I wish if someone could help me.

MY query goes like this

```
select date_trunc('day', t1.intime) AS Period, t4.outnodename, 
    count(t4.outnodename), sum(t2.cdrs)  from auditrtailreference t1
LEFT JOIN auditrtailreference t2 on t2.sourceid = t1.destinationid AND t2.event ='80' and t2.outnodename not like '%ABHISHEK%'
LEFT JOIN auditrtailreference t3 on t3.sourceid = t2.destinationid AND t3.event ='68' 
RIGHT JOIN auditrtailreference t4 on t4.destinationid like '%' || t3.destinationid || '%' AND t4.event ='68' AND t4.intime >= t3.intime AND (t4.outnodename like '%KAIF%_distributer' or t4.outnodename like '%KAIF%_Arch' or t4.outnodename like '%KAIF%_Distributer' or t4.outnodename like '%KAIF%_Distributor' or t4.outnodename like '%KAIF%_distributor') 
where t1.event ='67' and (t1.innodename like 'KAIF%ollect%r') AND t1.innodename not like '%FTP%' and t1.intime >= '2014/10/09 00:00' and t1.intime <= '2014/10/09 14:59' 
GROUP BY t4.outnodename, date_trunc('day', t1.intime);
```

The create statement is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE auditrtailreference
(
  event smallint,
  innodeid character varying(80),
  innodename character varying(80),
  sourceid character varying(300),
  intime timestamp without time zone,
  outnodeid character varying(80),
  outnodename character varying(80),
  destinationid character varying(300),
  outtime timestamp without time zone,
  bytes integer,
  cdrs integer,
  noofsubfilesinfile integer,
  recordsequencenumberlist character varying(1000),
  partial_cdrs integer,
  duplicate_cdrs integer,
  discarded_cdrs integer,
  created_cdrs integer,
  corrupted_cdrs integer,
  created_files integer,
  duplicate_files integer,
  corrupted_files integer,
  partial_files integer,
  discarded_files integer,
  empty_files integer
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE auditrtailreference
  OWNER TO erix;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE auditrtailreference TO erix;

-- Index: audit_destid_index

-- DROP INDEX audit_destid_index;

CREATE INDEX audit_destid_index
  ON auditrtailreference
  USING btree
  (destinationid COLLATE pg_catalog."default" );

-- Index: audit_intime_index

-- DROP INDEX audit_intime_index;

CREATE INDEX audit_intime_index
  ON auditrtailreference
  USING btree
  (intime  DESC);

-- Index: audit_outtime_index

-- DROP INDEX audit_outtime_index;

CREATE INDEX audit_outtime_index
  ON auditrtailreference
  USING btree
  (outtime  DESC);

-- Index: audit_sourceid_index

-- DROP INDEX audit_sourceid_index;

CREATE INDEX audit_sourceid_index
  ON auditrtailreference
  USING btree
  (sourceid COLLATE pg_catalog."default" );
```

Comment: Paste the output of `explain analyze select date_trunc...` into your question. But things such as `not like '%FTP` and such as `like '%' || t3.destinationid || '%'` can't use an index. (Google `sargable` for more information.) Also, `like '%' || t3.destinationid || '%'` is unlikely to do what you think if `destinationid` is an id number. Paste the CREATE TABLE statement and a few INSERT statements into your question, too.

Comment: Thanks Mike for your response. The create table statement is as follows: I have pasted the create statement in the question itself

Comment: Your formatting is illegible, please fix it. Also need `explain analyze` output.